# How to display taxonomy term image in a view

Tags: views, nodes, entities, taxonomy-terms, media

I have image field in taxonomy tags. Tags are term referenced in article content type, so now I want to show image field of my taxonomy term in my view. I have tried but I did not find any possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you can add a relationship in advanced.
Search for your term reference field in it and add the relation.

Then go to fields and search for your image field which is inside of the taxonomy. That way you will be able to add the image.

Comment: You are welcome @Shakil. Happy Learning!!